# how to join with tables?

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

First I want to write a join query to get every doc and the subjects that he uploaded i used this query but it is not working well and showing all the subjects under one doctor and all i have to get the subjects of the course is the course ID

```
SELECT users.ID
     , fullname
     , Sub_ID
     , Sub_name
     , Sub_ext
     , Sub_path
     , subject.created_at
  FROM users
  JOIN subject 
    ON users.ID = subject.ID
  WHERE C_ID = '$C_ID'
```

Comment: Your link is not working, so it's hard to tell. But maybe try running it without the ` WHERE C_ID='$C_ID'` line? It seems like that might be filtering it down to one doctor.

Comment: @JohnDoe check that link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccGCZ.png

Comment: @JohnDoe all i have to get the subjects of the Course is Course ID so i have to use   ` WHERE C_ID='$C_ID'`

Comment: can you provide sample data of tables and your expected result too

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong...
Correct is...

```
 "SELECT u.ID,u.fullname,s.Sub_id,s.Sub_name,s.Sub_ext,s.Sub_path,s.Created_at
 FROM users u LEFT JOIN subject s
 ON u.ID=s.ID
 WHERE s.C_ID='.$C_ID.'";
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by using 2 queries 
first one to get doc in that course and the second one from the subjects that doctor give

```
$query      =    "SELECT `doc-course`.ID,fullname
                                    FROM `doc-course`
                                    JOIN users ON `users`.`ID` = `doc-course`.`ID`
                                    WHERE C_ID='$C_ID' ";
```

the second

```
$query2 = "SELECT Sub_ID,Sub_name,Sub_ext,Sub_path,`subject`.`created_at`
    FROM subject
    WHERE `subject`.`ID` = '$ID[$x]'
    ";
```